# Queries on Android Camera

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, 6.0-marshmallow

I know the concepts of camera driver and camera HAL(hardware abstraction layer) but I don't have much idea about the upper layers(camera service and application).

I want to know
1. Who and when is camera service created?
2. Is there a process for camera HAL or it runs in the context of camera service?

Answers w.r.t Qualcomm HAL would be more helpful but if not any HAL is OK for me.

Comment: Is there a problem with the camera on your Android device that you are trying to solve?

Comment: nopes...just want info...